# Using push() method and indexOf() method to remove/check duplicate dates from an array in AngularJS1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, duplicates, indexof, epoch

Iam able to pull EPOCH dates and convert them into a string successfully, however what I previously coded didnt check or remove duplicates. Anyone has an idea of what I can add to do so? In this case, the timestamp is the EPOCH date I pulled form the live data! ANGULARJS1

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateMap = {};
for (i = 0; i < dbData.length; i++) {
  let tmp_date_str = "";
  let tmp_date = new Date(dbData[i].TIMESTAMP);

  tmp_date_str += tmp_date.getFullYear();
  tmp_date_str += "-";

  if ((tmp_date.getMonth()+1) < 10) {
      tmp_date_str += "0";
  }

  tmp_date_str += (tmp_date.getMonth()+1);
  tmp_date_str += "-";

  if (tmp_date.getDate() < 10) {
      tmp_date_str += "0";
  }
  tmp_date_str += tmp_date.getDate();

    // make it a map, and if value for this string already exists, do nothing
  if (!dateMap[tmp_date_str]) {
    dateMap[tmp_date_str] = true;
  }
}
```

If you need to get your dates as an array just do

```
  var dates = Object.keys(dateMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to eliminate duplication:

```
const mySet= new Set(["one", "two", "three", "one"]);

mySet.has("one") // true            
mySet.size === 3); // true
```

The Set constructor can take an array of
items with which the set is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

For check and remove duplicates you can use `angular.equals`:

```
var newArray = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.dates, function(value, key) {
                var exists = false;

                angular.forEach(newArray, function(val2, key) {
                if(angular.equals(value.date, val2.date)){ exists = true }; 
                });

                if(exists == false && value.dates != "") { newArray.push(value); }
            });

            $scope.dates = newArray;
```